# Restriction on Token Transfer

Tags: contract-design

Would it be possible to create a smart contract that would have restrictions on token transfers?  Say if I wanted to issue token(s) to an ETH address but to only allow that token to be transferred one time (different ETH address) and back to the contract and burned.  If it is transferred more than once it would be invalidated and be made available for someone else.

Doable?

Comment: I know this question is not related but if you wanted to access the token with a paper wallet you would need to display both QR codes for your ETH address and Private Key.  Do you imagine a way to restrict the transfer of this from person to person to subvert the transfer rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That's doable. The tokens never really leave the backoffice. It's just that the wallets and their private keys let them see. That means the contract that manages circulation rules like you describe.